# Please help me to make my gallery work (jQuery; Coin Slider; Fancybox)

Tags: jquery, slider, fancybox

I'm new here and new in JQuery/Javascript - where I have 2 problems.

I really appreciate if you download the files [here](http://www.r-disain.planet.ee/my_2_problems.zip)! - because it's more simple way to make myself clear - I hope.

I use **Coin Slider** for the main gallery, where I need to see, under slideshow, all the gallery pictures in thumbs (small pictures used) and on slideshow, when clicked on pictures, it should open in fullscreen view (bigger pictures used) with the help of **Fancybox** lightbox gallery.

So...

**PROBLEM 1**: Under slideshow, show all pictures that are in the gallery, in thumbs. Currently not showing - managed to show a certain picture, but not to relate to all gallery.

**PROBLEM 2**: When clicked on the pictures, currently on slideshow - should open in the fullscreen view. Currently seems to be in conflict with **Coin Slider**, cause when **Coin Slider** is not linked in the `index.html` file, the fullscreen view works, but pictures are shown in list mode.

I believe and hope that there is small correction needed in the **Coin Slider** files for thumbs (problem 1) and some code correction in `index.html` for the fullscreen view (problem 2).

This was a long read - thank you for bothering to read it to the end and sorry for possible grammar errors (I'm a non-English speaker).

Comment: Please set up a codepen or JSfiddle that isolates the problem in a __live__ environment. That will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @Nick. I added the code to "codepen": http://cdpn.io/oIsGL.

Bit messy, cause joined 2 jqueries (coin-slider / fancybox) - dont know if its allowed in jquery.

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I found that is possible to execute a javascript call through `href` which works with Coin Slider. Example:

```
href="javascript:alert('hello');"
```

Theoretically, it would be possible to use that to open a specific element of a Fancybox gallery.

I'm working on an example right now.

EDIT:

Here it is. Lets say we have a Coin Slider like the following:

```
<div id="coin-slider">
    <a href="javascript:box(0);"><img src="img/small/1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="javascript:box(1);"><img src="img/small/2.jpg"></a>
    <a href="javascript:box(2);"><img src="img/small/3.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Then we can create a function called "box" with parameter "i" which will open a Fancybox gallery in position "i".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function box(i) {
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
                src  : 'img/big/1.jpg',
                opts : {
                    caption : 'Optional description 1'
                }
            },
            {
                src  : 'img/big/2.jpg',
                opts : {
                    caption : 'Optional description 2'
                }
            },
            {
                src  : 'img/big/3.jpg',
                opts : {
                    caption : 'Optional description 3'
                }
            }
        ], {
            loop : false, index : i
        });
    };
</script>
```

I'm using Fancybox 3, but I'm sure this can be edited to work with other versions as well.
Hope this help someone out there.